# null inference doesn't work when property name is computed (Typescript)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to play with mixins and as such I want to use "private" members, so I wont override anything on the base class. As I understand it, symbols are the proper way to do this. However, I run into a nagging issue:

```js
const sym = Symbol.for('__a');

class A {
    [sym]: number | undefined;
    __staticProp: number | undefined;


    foo() {
        const value = this[sym] ? this[sym] : 4; //typeof value is 'number | undefined' - but it should be just 'number'
        const value2 = this.__staticProp ? this.__staticProp : 4; //typeof value2 is just number, as expected
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This looks like it is behaving as I would expect, thanks to type inference. What is the behaviour here that you would expect instead? Are you expecting `value2` to be of types `number | undefined`?

Comment: @Squiggle no, I expect `value` to be to of type `number`. The ternary operator assures that `value` can't be undefined. Typescript does that with a property defined normally, like `__staticProp`. I edited the question to be more clear, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a current design limitation of TypeScript.  What you're trying to do is called "control-flow based narrowing".  In the expression `foo.bar ? foo.bar.baz : qux`, the compiler will *narrow* the type of `foo.bar` to something truthy after the `?` and before the `:`, since it knows if the control flow makes it there, then `foo.bar` is truthy.

As you've seen, this works for "normal" properties of string literal types, even with bracket notation, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#26424](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26424).  Unfortunately, support for unique symbol-keyed properties were [not implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26424#issuecomment-436110562).  There is an [existing issue, microsoft/TypeScript#23135](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23135) asking for this support, but it was closed as a duplicate of the general bracket-notation issue before the implementation that skipped it appeared.  Perhaps a new issue should be filed (referencing the existing issue), if you really feel strongly about it.

Until then, what can be done?  The easiest thing to do is to refactor so that the compiler really knows that `undefined` is not possible.  An expression like `x ? x : y` can almost always be simplified to `x || y`, and no control-flow analysis is needed. So:

```
    const value: number = this[sym] || 4; // okay
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeBbGBeGBlJAjEAbAdAGYgBOAFAOQD6VAhhQJQDcAsAFDvC60QQwCCMAN7sYYmAG0EiALoAuGGACuiLAFMSMAD4wlYACZrCASzBr9rDm3ExiIMg2Gib40JFgA3WriVqFy1Q1UGCgAC2MIKSQZbR0AFiYYZzEAX3YUmCA)